# Python 3.6 Installation failed

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to install python3.6 on windows server 2016. I have downloaded  `python-3.6.6rc1-amd64-webinstall`.Followed the default setting to install it. But during installation step I got the error message as `0x80070659-This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator`. I have talked with system administrator but he is not aware of this policy. Can you  please guide me to resolve this error?

Comment: you don't have permission to install it, you need administrator account

Comment: Left click and run as administrator?

Answer (score 81):

I experienced this very same problem, and **right-clicking** the setup file, then **Run As Administrator** solved it. (Credit to @Igwilliams, who suggested this in the comments).

This was actually very frustrating for me, because I was *logged in* as an administrator, but apparently that still wasn't enough, I had to do the Run as Administrator thing as well.

Comment: How might I uninstall the previous version, which requires elevation too?

Comment: My answer assumes you already have adminstrator privileges, are you saying you're being prevented from uninstalling python while being an administrator?

Comment: Exactly so. In the end I deleted the directory and removed python from my PATH and then installed from scratch. Not ideal though

Comment: This solved it for me. The installer asked me for admin privileges, and I granted them, but it was not enough. It only worked when I used right-klick and run as admin. (Python 3.7.9-64 on Windows Server 2016)

Comment: As for uninstallation, I ran into same issue. When it fails, click the link taking you to the logfile. At the top, look for the binary that was executed, in my case "C:\users\primary\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{1babc3bc-6a32-44f7-bf4d-60eec36c9ad1}\python-3.6.1.exe". Navigate to this path, and you can right-click and launch this binary as Administrator. This time, uninstall will be successful.

Comment: Right click and Run as Admin worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Login to the system using admin credentials and try installing it. Or when installing provide admin credentials to install it.

Answer (score -1):

- Run regedit
- Browse the registry to `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`
- Create `DisableMSI`, type: `REG_DWORD`, value = 0 (0 should allow you to install, it was originally 1)